# Objective-C Compiler And Editor

Tags: objective-c, windows, macos, compiler-construction

This is just an easy question! 
I want to lean some `objective-c` but the problem I don't have a mac I've only PC with windows 
is there any compiler and editor where I can type my code and run it on windows. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can learn Objective-C — for example, see [here](http://sweettutos.com/2012/08/11/objective-c-on-windows-yes-you-can/). But you won't be able to create OS X or iOS applications straight from a Windows machine.

You can try to install a Hackintosh or emulate OS X in VirtualBox or VMWare.

But, IMHO, all of this would be a real pain in the neck!

Comment: Thanx for your answer 
But on OSX still better i must wait untile i purchase a mac -_-