# Reading inputs from Keyboard in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to `Objective C`. But I know `C/C++`. I want to accept inputs from keyboard, let assume that its a program for adding 2 numbers.

So can I use `scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);` ?

Comment: If you are creating a command line util, yes you can. If it is a normal app, pls use the UI elements such as NSTextField to read he input. What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: @ Shanti K: The following is my code is this correct?#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main ()
{
  /* variable definition: */
  int a, b;
  int c;
 
  NSLog(@"Enter values for A & B: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
  
  c = a + b;
  NSLog(@"value of c : %d \n", c); 
  return 0;
}

Comment: Ok. can I install Objective C compiler in Windows 8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471448/objective-c-compiler-and-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objective C is a superset of regular C , so you can use all the C functions like scanf() or getchar() and similar!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You can also rename yours file to .mm and write:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

cin>>a>>b;
```

Comment: Hi actually what is the use of "using namespace"

Comment: @Arun, cin is defined in std namespace, so without `using namespace std;` you should write `std::cin>>a>>b;`.